# Why i used two variables , one didnot declar ,but didnot get global-variables?

Tags: javascript

First :

```
function A() {

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            //...
        }
        console.log(i); //i is undefined
       // i dont get global i
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            //...
        }

    }
```

When i execute A() , i donot get global var i .
But this:

```
    function B() {
       // i get global i
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            //...
        }
     }
```

When i execute B() , I get global i .
So why i cannot get the global when i execute A() ?

Comment: coz its not global variable. its only working inside for statement.

Comment: I modify this question , after B(), i can get global i .

Comment: check this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp , you don't need to initial the variable for FOR STATEMENT

Answer (score 0):

`i` is never globally scoped in your code. It is lexically scoped only within the confines of your `A` function.

Comment: it is actually scoped inside the function A()